# jquery traversing to parent to change css

Tags: jquery, css, closest

I have a multiple drop down lists on a page:

**HTML**

```
<div class="select-full">
    <select id="activitylevel" class="input_select step2-ddl c2-sb-enabled">
        <option selected="selected" value="-1">-- please select --</option>
        <option value="1">Step 1 </option>
        <option value="3">Step 2</option>
        <option value="4">Step 3</option>
    </select>
    <div class="c2-sb-wrap" tabindex="0">
        <div class="c2-sb-inner-wrap"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to apply a border to the div with class c2-sb-inner-wrap to any selects that have not been selected (value == -1)

I'm trying to use closest() and next/nextAll but it's not happening:

```
$('.step2-ddl').each(function() {

    if ($(this).val() == '-1') {
        $(this).closest('.select-full').nextAll('.c2-sb-inner-wrap').css('border-color', '#f86556').css('border-style', 'solid');
    }
    else {
        $(this).closest('.select-full').nextAll('.c2-sb-inner-wrap').css('border-style', 'none');
    }
});​
```

Comment: Do you want this border applied once on page load? Or do you want it changed each time an option is selected?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.find()` instead of `.nextAll()`

Like:

```
$(this).closest('.select-full').find('.c2-sb-inner-wrap')
       .css('border-color', '#f86556').css('border-style', 'solid');
```

As a side note, I'd suggest toggling classes rather than directly changing CSS properties, as it's both leaner and cleaner.